# why C# is not similar having by default public Access Modifiers in VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

In VB.NET it have by default public access modifier to declare the primitive data type and calling it in main() function but In c# it have by default private access modifier to declare the primitive datatype and calling it in main() function.
Is the reason is of loosely type and strictly type ...?

Comment: Because OOP endorses encapsulation and private access is of paramount importance in developing code that encapsulates state-transition in the class and exposes only API with well known behaviors.
The Open/closed principle of OOP is the reference logical framework of this way of thinking.
Letting the default access private, enforces this conception although most code guidelines (and checkers like StyleCop for C#) suggest that you explicitly declare the access modifiers of any class member.

Comment: If all languages were identical in all features, we wouldn't *have* multiple languages. As it is, I'm not sure what "declare the primitive datatype and calling it in main() function" is meant to mean.